# How to achieve this layout properly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to have list items with a layout like below, with a circle that has an image, at right of the circle a title, the date of the post and then the category of the post. And at right of the list item should appear the button.

[image]

I have this code to achieve this layout using flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/muLh5v4n/2/. But its not working properly, the title, post date and category are not at the right of the image, are below the image.

HTML:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="bg-custom-gray-dark">
      <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <ul class="list-group list">
              <li class="list-group-item bg-custom-light2 py-4">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                  <form class="col-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group list_search">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <span class="input-group-text search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control shadow-none search-input p-0" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Search...">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
    
                  <div class="col-7 text-right">
                    <div class="dropdown filters mr-3">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Filter 2 <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                          </a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown filters">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Filter2 <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                          </a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="post-info">
                  <img src="http://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/75x75.png?css=%7B%22border-radius%22%3A%2215px%22%7D">
                  <h3>Title of the post</h3>
                  <span>post date</span>
                  <span>Categorqy of the post</span>
                </div>
                <div class="post-button ml-auto">
                  <button>Read</button>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">item2</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">item3</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">...</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this; you can further style the elements; but basically this component should display as you intend. Also this is **using only Bootstrap Classes**, custom css is only for the example.

```css
.list-item {
   max-width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="list-item border d-flex align-items-center">
   <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="rounded-circle" alt=""></div>
   <div class="ml-2">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>some-text</p>
      <span>Span</span>
   </div>
   <div class="ml-auto mr-2"><button>Button</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know why there is more space between the paragraph and span than the space between the title and the paragraph?

Comment: That's because by default paragraphs have a small `margin-bottom`, you can remove it with CSS or adding `mb-0` class to the paragraph :)

Answer (score 3):

This is another aproach.

```css
ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     width: 500px;
     border: 1px solid gray;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}

.picture_round{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  display: block;
}

.dsp_flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.middle_section{
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

ul li button{
  margin-right: 20px;
}

ul li{
  padding: 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

.title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.category{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px; 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <div class="dsp_flex">
   <img src="https://ph-test-11.slatic.net/p/4/yd-m6-kids-electric-ride-on-toy-car-4-wheels-red-6663-9385349-68cc46bb43f6fc801db86e9994dd6dba-catalog.jpg_340x340q80.jpg_.webp" class="picture_round">
   <div class="middle_section">
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="description">lorem ipsum ipsum</div>
    <div class="category"> category </div>
   </div>
   <button>Button</button>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div class="dsp_flex">
   <img src="https://ph-test-11.slatic.net/p/4/yd-m6-kids-electric-ride-on-toy-car-4-wheels-red-6663-9385349-68cc46bb43f6fc801db86e9994dd6dba-catalog.jpg_340x340q80.jpg_.webp" class="picture_round">
   <div class="middle_section">
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="description">lorem ipsum ipsum</div>
    <div class="category"> category </div>
   </div>
   <button>Button</button>
  </div>
 </li>
  <li>
  <div class="dsp_flex">
   <img src="https://ph-test-11.slatic.net/p/4/yd-m6-kids-electric-ride-on-toy-car-4-wheels-red-6663-9385349-68cc46bb43f6fc801db86e9994dd6dba-catalog.jpg_340x340q80.jpg_.webp" class="picture_round">
   <div class="middle_section">
    <div class="title">titletitle title</div>
    <div class="description">lorem ipsum ipsum lorem ipsum ipsum</div>
    <div class="category"> categorycategory </div>
   </div>
   <button>Button</button>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This really does work, I'd just say try to use as many bootstrap classes only as possible to avoid overriding too much CSS, many of the classes you added are available in bootstrap out-of-the-box, which helps keep the html a lot cleaner

Comment: Why is not working? I just gave him an option without using bootstrap. I am a little negative about it and i try to make my own classes that i reuse and build everything from scratch.

Comment: I didn't say this is not working, I actually said it DOES work.. Just that since OP is using Bootstrap, it'd be easier to use classes already available in bootstrap :) it is a good solution to use if Bootstrap is not available though

Comment: Oh, I just misread ! Sorry about that ! I try to avoid bootstrap because first of hand, i don't understand the classes and second, i cannot remember them :)).

Comment: It's easly for me to build from 0 than using Bootstrap

Comment: Don't worry, and keep practicing, you'll get to learn them really easily with time and trust me it will help you saving LOTS of time, specially with the utility classes... Although it's really good to fully master barebones css, at the end of the day you can recreate everything by hand, and even more now with `flexbox` and CSS Grid

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 has a class called `.flex-row` that we can use.

Lets do this using only Bootstrap classes and flex.

**1.** Add `flex-row` class to the `list-group-item`.

**2.** Add `d-flex` to `post-info`.

**3**. Place the text into a `d-flex flex-column` div.

```
<li class="list-group-item d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
<div class="post-info d-flex">
    <img src="http://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/75x75.png?css=%7B%22border-radius%22%3A%2215px%22%7D">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <h3>Title of the post</h3>
        <span>post date</span>
        <span>Categorqy of the post</span>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="post-button ml-auto">
    <button>Read</button>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/muLh5v4n/13/

You can later on use Bootstraps built in padding classes to make it space out nicely.